# How to retrieve the ID of selected option from select control in Angular?

Tags: angular

In my Angular app, I am retrieving data from this JSON file.

Books.json:

```
[
    {
    "bookID": 1,
    "title": "Goodnight Moon",
    "author": "Margaret Wise Brown",
    "publicationYear": "1953"
    },
    {
    "bookID": 2,
    "title": "Winnie-the-Pooh",
    "author": "A. A. Milne",
    "publicationYear": "1926"
    }
]
```

Here is the code I am using to read the JSON:

**add-reader.component.ts:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getAllBooks()
        .subscribe(
          (data: Book[]) => this.allBooks = data,
          (err: any) => console.log(err),
          () => console.log('all done getting books')
    );
   }
```

Then, I am then populating a select control successfully like this:

**add-reader.component.html**

```
<select name="bookDropDown" ngModel>
    <option [ngValue]="book.bookID" *ngFor="let book of allBooks">
        {{book.title}}
    </option>
</select>
```

When the form is submitted, the following code is executed:

**add-reader.component.ts**

```
saveReader(formValues: any): void {
    let newReader: Reader = <Reader>formValues;
    newReader.readerID = 0;

    this.dataService.addReader(newReader)
    .subscribe(
      (data: Reader) => console.log(data),
      (err: any) => console.log(err)
    );
  }
```

**data.service.ts:**

```
addReader(newReader: Reader): Observable<Reader> {
    return this.http.post<Reader>('/api/readers', newReader, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    });
  }
```

**reader.js:**

```
router.route('/')
.post(function(req, res) {
var data = getReaderData();
var nextID = getNextAvailableID(data);
var newReader = {
            readerID: nextID,
            name: req.body.name,
            weeklyReadingGoal: req.body.weeklyReadingGoal,
            totalMinutesRead: req.body.totalMinutesRead,
            bookID: req.body.bookID
};
data.push(newReader);

saveReaderData(data);
res.status(201).send(newReader);
});
```

When I submit the form, I'm pushing to **readers.json**, which contains several of these objects:

```
 {
    "readerID": 1,
    "name": "Maria",
    "weeklyReadingGoal": 350,
    "totalMinutesRead": 5600,
    "bookID": 91
}
```

Currently, when I submit the form, all values are being added except for **bookID**.

How can I pass the bookID in from the Select control so that it is populating the JSON file?

Many thanks!

Comment: Replace `[value]="book"` by `[ngValue]="book.bookID"`. https://angular.io/api/forms/NgSelectOption

Comment: Hi @JBNizet, thanks for your suggestion. I've tried this, but unfortunately it still produces the same result. The readerID, name, weeklyReadingGoal & totalMinutesRead are populated in readers.json, but no bookID unfortunately.

Comment: Your select doesn't use ngModel and doesn't have formControlName either. So it's not bound to anything. Do the same thing as you're doing for the other form controls.

Comment: @JBNizet I've added ngModel & a name to the select, but it's still behaving the same. I've updated my code in my question to show these changes

Comment: @JBNizet I think the issue is with `bookID: req.body.bookID` line in **reader.js** above

Comment: That's not how you bind a form control to a model. Post a **complete** minimal example reproducing the issue, so that we can know how you're binding the other form controls.